# Schläfli-type integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to compute the following integral
$$I \triangleq \int_0^{+\infty}\exp{\left(-x-\frac{1}{cx}\right)}x^{-(b+1)}dx,$$

for $b, c$ strictly positive reals. From Wolfram, I obtain that
$$I = 2 c^{b/2}K_b\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{c}}\right),$$

where $K_b$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind (as defined in e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)).

I have tried to obtain this formula by applying Schläfli's integral
$$J_b(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\left(\frac{z}{2}
\right)^b\int_{-\infty}^0\exp{\left(x-\frac{z}{4x}\right)}x^{-(b+1)}dx,$$

where $z$ is a complex number in a domain such that $z^b$ is well-defined (e.g. $\mathbb{C}\setminus i\mathbb{R}_-$) and $J$ is the Bessel function of the first kind (see also the link above). Schläfli's integral is stated in [DLMF, Bessel Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9).

Using the change of variables $x = -t$ and Schläfli's integral, we obtain
$$I = (-1)^{b+1}\int_{-\infty}^0\exp{\left(t-\frac{-1}{ct}\right)}t^{-(b+1)}dt = (-1)^{b+1} 2 \pi i c^{b/2}i^{-b}J_b\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}i\right).$$

I think it is possible to conclude from this using relations between Bessel functions, but I haven't been able to do so. Does anyone have any ideas ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: have you proved that this integral converges?

Comment: Hello ! I think the integral converges for all values of $b, c > 0$. In fact, let $f(x) \triangleq \exp\left(-x-\frac{1}{cx}\right)x^{-(b+1)}$. Then, $f(x) \sim \exp(-x)$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \sim \exp\left(-\frac{1}{cx}\right)x^{-(b+1)}$ as $x \to 0$. And so the integral converges because $\int_1^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$ and $\int_0^1\exp\left(-\frac{1}{cx}\right)x^{-(b+1)}dx \leq \int_0^1x^{-(b+1)}dx$ both converge.

Comment: You should take care that Schläfli's integral is taken along a contour which gives 2 contributions: when parametrized $z=-t-i\varepsilon$ and $z=-t+i\varepsilon$ must be taken into account.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for the hint ! You are right, I have to take into account the integral along the second line also. This also means that the first equality in the last set of equations in wrong.

Comment: @kantadou I would rather say that the second equality is wrong. The first one may follow from the definition of $I$, if you have a clear definition of $(-1)^{b+1}$ and of $t^{-b+1}$ when $t<0$.

Comment: Schläfli integral leads you ton complicated determination issues. One of the integral representation of $K_b$,  [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10), directly gives the Wolfram result.